# Spring JMX interception

Tags: spring, jmx, spring-jmx

I want to intercept all requests sent from JMX to setup some context configuration, is there any mechanism for doing that?

If there isn´t a place to put an interceptor for all MBeans, the alternative that I have in mind is to proxy each MBean.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are looking for; you can [proxy individual MBeans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-proxy). To proxy the entire server, you would need to implement your own connector.

Maybe the `MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean` would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I would take a look at the MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean.